# MongoDB timestamp field sampling and aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I'm kind of new to MongoDB, so bear with me.

Consider a collection which is built from documents in the form of the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("538d87a36da0bab7ff1a827d"),
    "resource_id", "some_id",
    "server_ts" : 1401784227674.05214213,
    "location" : [ 
        34.8383953, 
        32.1098175
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Documents are being added per resource in a relatively fast rate, so I end up with a high resolution of timestamped locations (approx. half a second resolution) based on `server_ts`.
I'd like to be able to query the collection based on a resource id, but return documents in a a lower resolution (e.g. 5 seconds resolution, rather than the original 0.5).
In another words I'd like to divide the time to ranges of 5 seconds, and for each range, fetch one document which falls in that range (if it actually exists).
Is there a convenient way in mongodb either in the Aggregation framework or in the standard query interface to 'sample' data based on this criteria?

Obviously this can be done in server side code (Node.js in my case), but I still wonder if there's a better alternative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store timestamp as an integer you can use [modulo](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/) operator.
    db.coll.find( { ts: { $mod: [ 5, 0 ] } } )

This will return all documents where value of the `ts` is e.g. 1401784227670, 1401784227675, 1401784227680...

Of course, this only works if you have only one document in the same second.

To filter out "duplicates" you can use aggregation like this:

```
db.x.aggregate([
    { $match : { ts : { $mod : [ 5, 0] } } },
    { $sort : { ts : 1 } }, /* without it $first is unpredictable */
    { $group : { _id : "$ts", location : { $first : "$location" } /* etc. */ } } 
]);
```